# want to remove a <li> from list with a code in functions

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function

i have a wordpress plugin where the support is symply bad. this is a plugin for a shuttle service. to book a shuttle, the visitor have to pick a boarding point and a destination point.

both are configured in a list and are used for both select lists. some are used for boarding, other for the destination.

in boarding i want to hide/some items, and this is not possible by any configuration af the plugin.

i hope someone understand my issue. first i give some code how the form is build, then what i have try but it does not work...

first the code:

```
<div class="mage_input_select mage_bus_boarding_point">
<div class="route-input-wrap"><input id="bus_start_route" type="text" class="mage_form_control" name="bus_start_route" value="Fürth" placeholder="Please Select" autocomplete="off" required=""></div>
<div class="mage_input_select_list" style="display: block;">
<ul>
<li data-route="Bruck a/d Großglocknerstraße"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>Bruck a/d Großglocknerstraße</li>
<li data-route="Führt - Mittersill"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>Führt - Mittersill</li><li data-route="Fürth"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>Fürth</li>
<li data-route="Kaprun"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>Kaprun</li>
<li data-route="Salzburg Flughafen"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>Salzburg Flughafen</li>
<li data-route="Taxenbach"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>Taxenbach</li>
<li data-route="test patrick"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>test patrick</li>
<li data-route="Zell am See"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>Zell am See</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

what i want to hide...

```
<li data-route="Führt - Mittersill"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>Führt - Mittersill</li>
<li data-route="test patrick"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>test patrick</li>
```

and what i did try for my functions.php file:

```
function remove_list_items_from_page_content($content) {
   
    $content = preg_replace('/<li data-route="(Führt - Mittersill|test patrick)">.*?<\/li>/', '', $content);
    return $content;
}

function modify_page_content() {
   
    if (is_page(130)) { 
       
        $page_content = get_post_field('post_content', 130); 
        
        
        $new_page_content = remove_list_items_from_page_content($page_content);
        
        
        $new_page_content = wp_kses_post($new_page_content); 
        wp_update_post(array('ID' => 130, 'post_content' => $new_page_content)); 
    }
}
add_action('wp', 'modify_page_content');
```

But it is not working, what is wrong?

the page with the form have ID-130 and is my start-page...

I do not know if it is forbidden here to give the url of my develop page?

Comment: The remove function seems to work fine. See https://3v4l.org/sAIUv

Comment: Are those elements always the same? So in boarding, it will always be those exact elements - `<li data-route="Führt - Mittersill">...` and `<li data-route="test patrick">...`

Answer (score 3):

You *can*  use CSS to do that in the following way, using the "data-route" attribute in a selector:

```css
li[data-route="Führt - Mittersill"],
li[data-route="test patrick"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="mage_input_select mage_bus_boarding_point">
<div class="route-input-wrap"><input id="bus_start_route" type="text" class="mage_form_control" name="bus_start_route" value="Fürth" placeholder="Please Select" autocomplete="off" required=""></div>
<div class="mage_input_select_list" style="display: block;">
<ul>
<li data-route="Bruck a/d Großglocknerstraße"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>Bruck a/d Großglocknerstraße</li>
<li data-route="Führt - Mittersill"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>Führt - Mittersill</li><li data-route="Fürth"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>Fürth</li>
<li data-route="Kaprun"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>Kaprun</li>
<li data-route="Salzburg Flughafen"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>Salzburg Flughafen</li>
<li data-route="Taxenbach"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>Taxenbach</li>
<li data-route="test patrick"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>test patrick</li>
<li data-route="Zell am See"><span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>Zell am See</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly why I asked my question on the OP. +1